# Mongoose not picking up on callback variables for render

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

```
app.get("/users/:id", function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(foundUser)
        }
    })
    Item.countDocuments({ UID: req.params.id }, function (err, itemCount) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(itemCount)
        }
    })
    Item.find({ UID: req.params.id }, function (err, foundItems) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(foundItems)
        }

    })
    res.render("users/show", { user: foundUser, newListItems: foundItems, itemCount: itemCount})
```

For some reason this wont render and keeps saying that the variables dont exist despite the callbacks above. Using EJS for render.

Comment: console.log doesn't intend to return anything. Use ```return``` instead and keep ```console.log``` for error output

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading the code incorrectly, but aren't the callback variables out of scope for the res.render method?
You may need to return the callbacks from each of the Mongoose queries and store them in variables that are within the scope of the res.render method.

Comment: yeah how would I do this... I am kind of nooby with JS but ik in python you could use something like a global variable... would that work here

Comment: Thanks a lot... that works and I now realize that you cant access those variables if they aren't in scope of the callback. Thanks!

Comment: You can just declare the variable inside of the app.get method

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Richie, you cannot access the variables from.inside the callbacks in the outer scope

```
app.get("/users/:id", function (req, res) { 
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundUser) { 
        if (err) { console.log(err) } 
        else {
            console.log(foundUser) 

            Item.countDocuments({ UID: req.params.id }, function (err, itemCount) { 
                if (err) { console.log(err) } 
                else { 
                    console.log(itemCount) 
                    Item.find({ UID: req.params.id }, function (err, foundItems){ 
                        if (err) { console.log(err) } 
                        else { 
                        console.log(foundItems);   
                        res.render("users/show", { user: foundUser, newListItems: foundItems, itemCount: itemCount})
                        } 
                    });
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Notice that I've put the `res.render` method inside the callbacks so that the variables are available to it.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Marcel Djaman, You should probably use `async/await` to make code more readable. Read more about `async/await` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```
app.get("/users/:id", async function (req, res) { 
    try {
        const foundUser = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        console.log(foundUser) 

        const itemCount = await Item.countDocuments({ UID: req.params.id });
        console.log(itemCount) 

        const foundItems = await Item.find({ UID: req.params.id });
        console.log(foundItems);   
        res.render("users/show", { user: foundUser, newListItems: foundItems, itemCount: itemCount});
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
});
```

You can notice how much simpler this code is than the one above it.

Comment: callback hell! Not proper way

Comment: why not using async/await

Comment: Yes that would've been better

Comment: Not really familiar with async/await... what are it's benefits as opposed to callbacks?

Comment: @infecting Better read it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function